# Is there any way to configure php to always set $_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH']?

Tags: php, http-headers, content-length

I'm working on carddav client. As server i use davical v. 0.9.9.6. I don't understand why i'm getting invalid content-type error when http headers contains correct value. I look into source code and found this condition:

```
if ( isset($_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH']) && $_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH'] > 7) {...
```

After little research I found php set `$_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH']` only with POST method and uploading file. Is there any way to configure php to always set `$_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH']`?
I'm asking generally, not only for this case...

//EDIT
I'm doing HTTP PUT request to davical server (using php curl).

```
PUT /caldav.php/testuser/contacts/newc.vcf HTTP/1.1
Host: davical  
Content-Type: text/vcard;

BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
FN:ME
...
```

On davical side is condition testing CONTENT_LENGTH which is not set. So it's a davical bug?

//EDIT 2

Finally I figure it out!
PUT request with calback readfunc requires set INFILE_SIZE via curl_setopt(...)
There is none auto value and put Content-Length field manualy into header is also wrong. 
Example (incorrect):

```
// PUT REQUEST
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,"Content-Length: $length");  //mistake
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_PUT,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_READFUNCTION,array($this,'readfunc'));
....
--------------------------------------------------------------
// WIRESHARK TCP STREAM DUMP
PUT /caldav.php/testuser/contacts/novy.vcf HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Host: davical
Accept: */*
Content-Type: text/vcard
Content-Length: xxx
Expect: 100-continue

HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

155
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
...
END:VCARD

0

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
----------------------------------------------------------------
// On server side
isset($_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH'])==false
```

Second (correct) example

```
// PUT REQUEST
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_INFILESIZE,$length);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_PUT,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_READFUNCTION,array($this,'readfunc'));
....
--------------------------------------------------------------
// WIRESHARK TCP STREAM DUMP
PUT /caldav.php/testuser/contacts/novy.vcf HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Host: davical
Accept: */*
Content-Type: text/vcard
Content-Length: xxx
Expect: 100-continue

HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
...
END:VCARD
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
----------------------------------------------------------------
// On server side
isset($_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH'])==true
```

Comment: If the problem is with content type then what content length has to do with it ?

Comment: Failed test on content_legth cause error message on content type on the end. That conditon encapsulate importat piece of code. It's not my code. It's davical (opensource) project. I'm writing client and found this problem.

Comment: There was a DAViCal bug around this which has since been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Although i have never used CONTENT_LENGHT i can tell you why this is probably happening:

In a request, you don't have to set the Content-Lenght header... IT IS NOT MANDATORY. Except for specific situations. If your POSTed content is of type "multipart/form-data" it becomes necessary to use content-lenght for each part because each part is seperated by a boundary and each part will have its own headers...

For example:

```
Content-Type: MultiPart/Form-Data
Boundary: @FGJ4823024562DGGRT3455

MyData=1&Username=Blabla&Password=Blue


@FGJ4823024562DGGRT3455==
Content-Type: image/jpef:base64
Content-Lenght: 256

HNSIFRTGNOHVDFNSIAH$5346twSADVni56hntgsIGHFNR$Iasdf==
```

So here this is a crude example of what a multi part request works, you see that the second part has a content-lenght. This is why sometimes the content-lenght is set and sometimes not, because you need to read X bytes before finding another boundary and extract the correct data.

It doesn't mean your server will never send it in in other cases, but my 2 cents are this is the case right now. Its because you are not in POST, but in some other modes.

Comment: `Content-Length` is not required when sending multipart requests either.

Comment: It isn't? i always had to put it in, but maybe i read the docs wrong, anyway, you can't rely on that because in most cases it won't be there...

Comment: Actually, it's there most of the times. `Content-Length` is usually sent, along a `Connection: close` header. Once the server receives the amount of data as defined in the `Content-Length` header, it will automatically close the connection. When it's not sent, most servers will still accept the request, but the client will have the responsibility of closing the connection. All in cases though, `Content-Length` is ignored by the server, therefore usually not sent, when `Transfer-Encoding` is provided (e.g.: chunked), as when the client is streaming data.

Answer (score 1):

Only requests that have a *request body* have a content length request header (or at least only then it makes sense) and so therefore the `$_SERVER` variable is set.

If you need it to be always set (which I think is bogus), you can do this yourself on the very beginning of your script:

```
isset($_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH']) && $_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH'] = 0;
```

Assuming that if it is not set, it's of zero length. See as well [Improved handling of HTTP requests in PHP](https://gist.github.com/1028251).

Comment: I'have request body. I do PUT request with vcard content (client). On server side it's also php and there is condition testing CONTENT_LENGTH which is not set. Server side is not my code so if it's possible a would like to aviod changes there

Comment: If server-side is not your code, and it contains a bug because it expects a header which is truly optional, you should file a bug report. Which library are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You could probably set them by yourself. Why do you need that this values are set? And what should they set to?

> Maybe you're missing information on $_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE'] or
>   $_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH'] as I did. On POST-requests these are
>   available in addition to those listed above.

-> http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php#86495